# PopToViewController in UIStoryboard application

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, xcode4.5, poptoviewcontroller

I have made on application using Xcode 4.5.
and also use UIStoryboard in this application.

In this app, I push from one ViewController to second ViewController and then push from second ViewController to third ViewController.

Now, How I can Pop (back) directly from third ViewController to first ViewController.

Is it possible or not ?
If possible, then How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible , Just use this..

```
  [self.navigationController popToViewController: [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

You can change value of objectAtIndex with any controller's value you want to pop

Answer (score 0):

use this methode

```
popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
```

apple doc

Pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view controller and updates the display.

- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated

Parameters
animated : Set this value to YES to animate the transition. Pass NO if you are setting up a navigation controller before its view is displayed.

Return Value : An array of view controllers that are popped from the stack.

Example of use

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **popToViewController** and check if the view controller is in the stack by using the below code.

```
for (UIViewController *aViewController in self.navigationController viewControllers)
{
    if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[firstViewController class]])
                        {
                            firstViewController *FVC = (firstViewController*)aViewController;
                          [self.navigationController popToViewController:FVC animated:YES];
                        }
                    }
```

Hope this helps.